# Visual Studio, hide C#-method from external library from IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

I know that I can use `[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` to hide methods from IntelliSense when building my own libraries but. As a Resharper/Rider user I also know that this is not always respected (based on settings).

I'm currently working on a project where we have some external dependencies that we have "improved" with some extension methods and I would really like to hide some methods from the external library from IntelliSense.

**Example:**

The external library has a method called `LogIfFailed`, the default implementation logs the errors with LogLevel Information so I have created an extension `LogErrorIfFailed` that will log the error with LogLevel Error. Since we filter logs based on these it's quite important to get this right and it's really easy to mix these two.

So I think I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to hide methods from external libraries? Either with "vanilla" Visual Studio or with Resharper/Rider?
2. Or does anyone have another idea or suggestion on how to make sure that we don't accidentally use the wrong method? I've been thinking about plugins or maybe some analyzer that runs on build.

Cheers!

Update: To be clear, the external library is a NuGet package that I have no control over.

Comment: Use the `internal` access modifier

Comment: Are you the author of the external library or is it controlled by someone else?

Comment: Sorry, could have made that clear. It not my library, external from NuGet

Comment: @DanielA.White it not my library. Then I would probably just have changed the implementation.

Comment: You could write an analyzer to throw build time errors